# How to load mesh from .obj file using unity script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the mesh from an .obj file.

I'm not doing a game from scratch but rather a mod for an already built game, so I only have scripts to load new things. I tried `Resources.Load()` but nothing was loaded.
The exact code I tried is: `MeshFilter meshObject = Resources.Load<MeshFilter>("Resources/meshName");`
I also tried with Mesh instead of MeshFilter.

The file is in the folder "Resources" (the folder itself is where the main.cs is, inside the visual studio project), in case this is important.

Something else I tried is loading the .obj as a GameObject and then get its mesh:

```
GameObject meshObject = Resources.Load<GameObject>("name");
Mesh myMesh = meshObject.GetComponent<Mesh>();
```

This got me a null exception.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting an old post. I just wanted to write a quick reminder for everybody seeing this: remember to instantiate the object you load from resources! i.e. `GameObject instantiatedModel = Instantiate(meshObject)`

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is correct. Unity considers resources in the resources folder as GameObjects. So you load in the game object of your mesh as you are, then you have to get the component. You forgot to specify the component, so this should work just fine:

```
GameObject meshObject = Resources.Load<GameObject>("name");
Mesh myMesh = meshObject.GetComponent<Mesh>();
```

If this is what you are already trying, it is an issue of your asset file that we can't help without more information on where the files is from/how it is made. Try a MeshFilter with this method as well.

Comment: It is indeed what I tried already. The .obj file was made by me in 3ds max; The file name is SilverAssets.obj and it contains a single mesh called "Silver_ears_n_tail". The file works fine in any 3d viewer and even in a Unity project. The exact error I'm getting is ` NullReferenceExpection: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an Object` and I believe this happens when trying to use the mesh obtained.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67082756/7111561) you should probably load the asset as a `GameObject`.

```
var meshObject = Resources.Load<GameObject>("SilverObject");
```

Can't confirm it since only on the phone currently - actually I believe this only works for `.prefab` files.

However, if it works then still `Mesh` is no component so using `GetComponent<Mesh>()` won't work.

you can try rather using

```
var mesh = meshObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
```

or also

```
var mesh = meshObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter().sharedMesh;
```

instead.

---

In general you can also use [Runtime OBJ Importer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/runtime-obj-importer-49547) in order to load any `OBJ` + `MTL` file on runtime

And also note from the official [Best Practices for `Resources`](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7):

> **Don't use it!**

Answer (score 0):

When I took `GameObject` from the ".obj" file like this:

```
var obj =  Resources.Load<GameObject>("file");
```

Then I noticed that in this `GameObject` (`obj`) there is only one `Transform` component and one child `GameObject`. And if we take this child `GameObject`:

```
var childObj = obj.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
```

Then we will see 3 components already: `Transform`, `MeshFilter` and `MeshRenderer`.

Thus, I think that anyone who has encountered a similar problem and cannot take a `Mesh` from an ".obj" file, this code should help:

```
var mesh = Resources.Load<GameObject("file").transform.GetChild(0)
                    .GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
```